# MAC (message authentication code) standard size

Tags: macos, security, implementation, sha

Which is the standard size of the `MAC` generated with `SHA-2`?

it is safe if I trunk the message and then send it to destination ?

Thank you in advance for your consideration

Comment: SHA-2 is a collection of functions with different output sizes; there's no single standard one.

Comment: So, I can send a MAC with the size that I prefer, right?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "prefer" ... they're not arbitrary. There's 4 sizes to choose from.

Comment: Ok, excuse me but I'm not an expert. Hence, which are these 4 sizes? I'm actually producing a MAC with a size of 32 bytes. It's the smallest one or I can reduce it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, do not use only the SHA2 hash funcion, but use HMAC (with SHA2).

Now for answering your question: In theory, you can use any size for your MAC, depending on your security requirements. However, **the most recommended standard tag size is [128 bits](https://www.keylength.com/)** (16 bytes).

Comment: Ok, thank you. However I have a problem. I'm developing an application for a context in which there are bandwidth limitations. The payload that I'm sending is at least of 21 bytes. In that case, is it correct to send a MAC with a length higher than the message ? Moreover can you send me some references about the standard raccomandation ? 
Thank you a lot for your consideration.

Comment: I added a ref to https://www.keylength.com/, which lists some publications on current recommended key lengths. The MAC should always be the same size, no matter what the length of the message is.

Comment: I screwed up and accidentally put 256 bits, but MACs are not prone to birthday attacks, so this should be 128 bits.

Comment: Ok thank you, but, maybe there has been a misunderstanding. I need to know which is (if there is) a standard size for the tag t  generated by a  t = MAC(k,m) where k is key of 256 bits and m is the message.

Comment: Yes , I actually meant the tag, I updated the answer accordingly.